# Remove Select option after doing the action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Select option where if I select any option related div Shows up. Upto this it's fine. But I am wanting to make something like if I select the option it will display the related div but option it self will be removed. 
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vWLsU/513/)**

Is this possible ? Any help will be appreciated.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-location').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
        div = $('#' + location);

        $('div').hide();
            div.show();

    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry my English is bad. Your example didn't match. I am wanting to remove that option after displaying related div :)

Comment: You mean remove it from the list entirely?

Comment: Yes was wanting something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my answer to reflect the update in the question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-location').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
        div = $('#' + location);
        var selIndex = $("#contact-location").prop('selectedIndex');
        $("#contact-location").prop(selIndex).remove();
        $('div').hide();
        div.show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwt73sj3/

`var selIndex = $("#contact-location").prop('selectedIndex');` here we set the select element index to a variable we can work with later.

`$("#contact-location").prop(selIndex).remove();` removed the index value from the select drop down.

Comment: This is Perfect and Thank you for Understanding my bad English and for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contact-location').change(function(){
            $('#contact-location option').show(); //clean alls
            $('option:selected',this).hide(); // hide selected
            var location = $(this).val(),
            div = $('#' + location);

            $('div').hide();
                div.show();

        });
})
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wilfredo1285/vWLsU/514/)

Comment: I wanted to entirely  remove the option list. Like the Example  the_pete gave. Sorry I English is bad. may be I couldn't Explain well.

Comment: @Raihan Don't worry. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not make things more generic at the same time?

```
$(function () {
    $('#contact-location').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        // show only correct location
        $('div').hide(); // maybe use a class rather than hiding every <div>
        $('#' + $this.val()).show();

        // show only alternate options
        $this.find('option').show();
        $this.find('option:selected').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to use click on the children of select (i.e. the options) and then hide this (which is the option). Then the value of the select still has the value of the selected option and you have to reset it manually (I used the content of the first child via the css :first-child selector but you could use anything else, too).

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#contact-location').children().click(function(){
        var $select = $(this).parent();
        var $clicked = $(this);
        var location = $clicked.val(); //is the same like $select.val()
        var $div = $('#' + location);

        $clicked.hide();
        $select.val($select.children(":first-child"));
        $div.show();
    });
});
```

I used $ before the names of some variables to indicate that these variables store jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected option like this:

```
$("option:selected", this);
```

From there you can hide or remove it:

```
$("option:selected", this).hide();
$("option:selected", this).remove();
```